# How can I create window with rounded borders and blured background on c# wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I want to create window with similar style to Window Start Menu. With rounded borders and blured background.
[Windows11 Start Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iEwV.jpg)

I tried haley.wpf, rounded borders created with , and my functions, but the borders were superimposed on the window, and therefore, whatever one may say, a rectangular window was obtained.
[Copied image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EluSR.png)

Comment: I believe you are referring to Mica - an opaque material that incorporates the user's theme and desktop wallpaper - which you can apply apps running on Windows 11 using the Windows App SDK as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/apply-mica-win32e?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077).

Comment: I must use Win32? Or it's possible on WPF?

Comment: WPF is a type of Win32 app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this XAML

```
<Window x:Class="NoBorderWindowTester.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NoBorderWindowTester"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
        AllowsTransparency="True" 
        WindowStyle="None"
        Background="Transparent" 
        >
    <Grid Background="Transparent">
        <Border CornerRadius="20" Background="BurlyWood" Width="600" Height="400" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Opacity="0.5">
            <Border.Effect>
                <BlurEffect Radius="5" KernelType="Gaussian"/>
            </Border.Effect>
        </Border>
        <TextBlock Text="Hello World" FontSize="45" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And you can change the effects (and everything else) on the border as you like it.

AND: To move the Window around, you can use this code

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        MouseDown += WindowMouseDown;
    }
    private void WindowMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
        if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
            DragMove();
    }
}
```